# The uniqueness of every linear operator on $V$ is a direct sum of a nilpotent and an invertible operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Halmos's book,the theorem says that:

Every linear transformation $A$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ can be decomposed to the direct sum of a nilpotent transformation and an invertible transformation. More detailedly,$V=\mathrm{Ker} (A^k)\oplus \mathrm{Ran} (A^k)$, where $k$ is the least integer s.t. $\mathrm{Ker} (A^k)=\mathrm{Ker} (A^{k+1})$.

In the proof it says that such decomposition is unique, he says that if there is another decomposition $V=M\oplus N$, then $N\in \mathrm{Ran} (A^i)$ for any $i$. I don't understand why $N\in \mathrm{Ran} (A^i)$ for any $i$ if $N$ is the subspace s.t. $A$ is invertible on it.